# Script that copies the contents of one cell and pastes it to another?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a script that copies and pastes the contents of one cell and pastes it into another cell and then clears the contents of the original cell. Both cells would be on the same spreadsheet. For example, I'd like to take the contents of cell B30, copy it into cell C10, and then clear the contents of cell B30 afterwards. The contents of the cells will be both strings of text and numbers.

Also, if there's another function that could help to print a certain section of the spreadsheet where these cells have been pasted after the initial script has been run, that would also be extremely helpful.

I'm assuming the initial code to copy and paste would be something along the lines of:

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('MySheet');
    var cell1 = sheet1.getRange('B30').getValue();
    ss.getSheetByName('MySheet').getRange('C10').setValue(cell1);
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Which application are you using? [tag:google-spreadsheet]? Consider adding these tags to your question then: [tag:google-spreadsheet] and [tag:google-apps-script] to make your question visible in these categories.

Comment: Yes, I am using Google Spreadsheet. Thank you for the suggestion; I have added the tags you mentioned.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have? Simply put it in a function with parameters?

Comment: It returns "function getValue() {/**/}" for multiple different lines whenever the contents of the original cells are copied and pasted into the new cells.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this? Some cells that I want to copy have numbers, some have text, and others may be blank.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty correct but I think it makes some confusion.
I rearranged your code below and added the "clear" part.

```js
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MySheet')

ss.getRange("C10").setValue(ss.getValue("B30"))
ss.getRange("C10").clear()
```